# how to generate randomly zeros and ones in a range with vba?

Tags: vba

I am trying to generate two random integers 0 and 1 in a range using vba; However when i run the sub it only fills the cells  with the **same value**; either 1 or 0. 
Where is the problem with the code?

```
Private Sub Btn_RandomNumbers_Click()
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c3:c302").value = 
Application.Choose(Application.RandBetween(1, 2), 0, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: you only run the `RandBetween` once, and then set the value of all cells in the range to the result. you have to loop the range, and call `RandBetween` for every cell.

Answer (score 1):

You will either need to loop and put the value in each cell individually or:

We can put the formula in the entire range, calculate and then reassign just the values to that range.

```
Private Sub Btn_RandomNumbers_Click()
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c3:c302")
    .Formula= "=RANDBETWEEN(0,1)"
    Application.Calculate
    .Value = .Value
 End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You generate the value once and the fill the whole range with this value. If you want each cell to be random, you need to create a loop and iterate through each cell.

Pseudo code:

```
For each Cell in Range Do
 'write random number in "Cell"
Next Cell
```